# UINavigation Controller Back Button not showing since upgrading to iOS 6

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

Here's my code for creating and displaying a back-button in my UINavigationController:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
backButton.title = @"Home";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

This worked perfectly in iOS 5, but since upgrading to iOS 6 its not working.

To make sure I take care of all possibilities, I've placed this code in my `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, and `viewWillAppear` - so its in 3 different methods - and its still not showing up.  Its also obviously in the rootViewController's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method - the one from which we are navigating to the other viewControllers.


I do also have a custom graphic in the banner/header of the rootViewController:

```
// Banner Code:
bannerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[bannerImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-banner@2x.png"]];    
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:bannerImageView];
```

But again, this worked perfectly well in iOS 5 and didn't conflict with the back-button. But now I'm just getting the banner/header graphic without the back-button.


One final note: the back button DOES show up for a split-second when I click on the EMPTY space where it SHOULD be. So its there - but you can't see it until you click on the empty space where it should be. It then shows up for a split-second - but then the App navigates back one screen so it immediately disappears. Very weird.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in assuming that your custom header graphic has something to do with your invisible back button (if you remove the header image, notice that the back button will become visible again).

If you aren't supporting firmwares older than iOS 5, use `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` to customize your header background:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-banner.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

(Note the absence of `@2x` from the image name - your app will know whether to use the standard or retina version of an image automatically.)

Comment: well I want the App to work with devices running **both** iOS 5 _AND_ iOS 6 - can I still use this `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics` method? If not, if `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics` only works for iOS 6, what do I do?

Comment: It is supported in iOS 5 and up.

Comment: Hmm - its not working. I did exactly as you said. Took out my banner code and put your suggested `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` code - and so I'm getting the banner, but the back-arrows are still not showing up...Any other ideas?

Comment: Actually, it is working :-)  Had some conflicting code, but once I made everything uniform it worked - many thanks!